# Is it conceivable, or at the least verisimilar, for Plutonium radioisotope generators/atomic batteries to power a small manufacturing town?

Tags: science-based, post-apocalypse

A small manufacturing town serves as a comparison. The worldbuilding significance is for an underground facility with, in addition to a medical center, small-scale chemical production, a machinist workshop, hydroponics, and cultured meat lab wherein living conditions are adjusted to minimize power consumption. The desired population is between 300 and 400 and plutonium is preferred because its half-life is 87 years, which satisfies my time preference.

If nuclear power is out of the question, would it be safer to have a facility powered by a dam?

Comment: You mean a [thermoelectric generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoelectric_generator) like those used in outer space on probes and robots or a regular boil-water-to-make-steam-to-turn-the-turbines atomic power plant? The second yes, the first no, because it's horribly inefficient -- so inefficient that it is used only when severe constraints impose such a solution.

Comment: @AlexP The former.

Answer (score 1):

Conceivable, maybe, but not realistic. Note that a typical Pu-238 battery with about 5kg of Plutonium just outputs 100 W of electrical power ([source](http://www.popsci.com/nasa-can-make-3-more-nuclear-batteries-and-thats-it)). Your small town will consume about 800 kW at least (rough estimate based on 2 kW/person energy consumption), counting for 8000 Pu batteries of about 40t of the rare and hard-to-obtain Pu-238.

A conventional power station (either a dam or a small fossil power plant or wind energy or solar energy and a conventional chemical battery for the night time) will do better.

Comment: Also, putting that much plutonium in close proximity is not a good idea.